# Jsp to Jsp but not functional?

Tags: jsp, templates, html

I'm trying to prepare approximately 10-15 JSP pages. But I want them to communicate each other... Then I use my Java Servlets class and java classes to make them functional. What I want It is just like templates I guess. and I must use header footer for all pages.

First of all, pages I make should forward page to page. when a clicked a button in "home.jsp" then it must move other jsp page which i click on "home.jsp".  I hope It make sense what I wrote...Sorry for my english.

How can I create just for seeing what It's happening in pages to pages.

Comment: Are you sure you are running your application on some web server and servlet container.

Comment: yea thats the thing actually...  I have a servlet and classes which make them functional... But for now I just want to make them empty.. Just want them to go page to page. And if you know what can I use for making them modern in view.

Comment: Pages I want like naked body. Then I put some clothes(servlets etc.) on to make them functional

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Which ide and server are you using? And what error you are getting? And by servlet container I mean an application that interacts with your http server like `tomcat` which co-ordinates with `apache` server.

Comment: Having servlets and jsps does not mean they will work like any other `html` file. They need to be run on some `server`.

Comment: I know. I'm using tomcat 7.0... And I have a loginpage.jsp and other pages but they are just html and poor Interface... Thats the thing I wanna change. I want them to have a good view with css or something like that. And then I want to use them with my servlets.

Comment: So, What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I dont know how can I run them on server with modifying them for modern view... I want good looking pages and not functional at this moment.. For example when i login and submit.It goes loginservlet then DB and then back to user to authentication.. I dont want that for now. When i click login ıt just goes next page. It shouldn't look if informations true or not

Comment: we can say that it is a prototype I'm going to use with my servlets later

Comment: Install netbeans or eclipse ide. They provide default server and containers. Create your web application project there and click the `run` button. It will do everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

*What I want It is just like templates I guess. and I must use header footer for all pages.*

To achieve this you can create custom tags and then use your own Html, Head and Body tags. You can put your common includes (header, footer, JS, CSS etc.) in these tags end expose them through tlds. In this way a developer can only concentrate on designing body part. You can find so many tutorials online for custom tags. See this for details [Custom Tags Jsp](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html)